# Azure Functions as Scheduler

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-data-factory

Is Azure functions a good alternative to Azure Data Factory to use as scheduler? It has blob trigger to monitor and can use C# to trigger databricks jobs using API. But is it a viable alternative.

Edited to add more information. Wanted to trigger a databricks job based on a trigger file but do not want to use Azure Data Factory or Data bricks job.

Comment: You said scheduler but you gave event based example. What scenario do you want to cover?

Comment: Trigger jobs in data bricks based on a trigger file but do not want to use Azure Data Factory or Databricks Jobs.

Comment: You want to trigger on file, where is the file stored?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would probably use simple logic app with Event Grid trigger on blob storage event blob created event. Based on trigger data I would call Databricks Job REST API.

I did entire demo below working in under 10 minutes so its fast to set up.

With this demo I used

[image]

And logic app setup as trigger

[image]

Where I strongly suggest to add prefix filter like

```
/blobServices/default/containers/<container_name>
```

So you don't fire too many logic apps from different containers as event grid reacts to all events in entire storage account.

And HTTP call like so

[image]

Of course at this point simply change clusters list to submitting job REST call.

And see execution like

[image]

[image]

Just make sure that EventGrid resource provider is registered or logic app will never fire off.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is brilliant. Thanks for the detailed note.